# How to select option with belongsToMany?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to populate the whole Edit form, but Select Box does not grab the value.

First time working with an eloquent relationship. I'm trying to access the Category method yet I get this error:

> Property [categoryId] does not exist on this collection instance.

And I installed `composer require laravelcollective/html` package.

```
{!! Form::select('categoryId',
     \Modules\Category\Entities\Category::pluck('title', 'id')->toArray(),
     old('categoryId', $faq->categories->categoryId) , [
    'class' => 'form-control',
    'id' => 'categoryId',
]) !!}
```

Category.php

```
class Category extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];
}
```

Faq.php

```
class Faq extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['subject', 'body', 'userId'];

    public function scopeSearch($query, $term)
    {
        return $query->when($term, function ($query, $term) {
            return $query->where('subject', 'like', "%{$term}%");
        });
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'userId');
    }

    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'faq_category', 'faqId', 'categoryId');
    }
}
```

Comment: so $faq->categories will be a collection of many Category, if the FAQ hasOne Category you can say $faq->category->id, but it all depends how you have your relationships setup, could you post the Category.php and the Faq.php ?

Comment: @MHewison - I updated my post.